# Initializing parent class' pointer using initializer list

Tags: c++, string, pointers, inheritance, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a class strings:

```
    class strings
    {
    protected:
    string *ptr;
    int size;
public:
    strings() {
        ptr = NULL;
        size = -1;
    }
    strings(int size) {
        this->size = size;
        ptr = new string[size];
    }
    string* retPtr() {
        return ptr;
    }
    void setPtr(int size)
    {
        ptr = new string[size];
        this->size = size;
    }
    strings(const strings& obj) {
        this->size = obj.size;
        for (int i = 0;i < size;++i)
            this->ptr[i] = obj.ptr[i];
    }
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, strings& obj) {
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Enter " << obj.size << " string one by one:\n";
        for (int i = 0;i < obj.size;++i)
        {
            getline(input, obj.ptr[i]);
        }
        return input;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const strings& obj) {
        cout << "Strings are:\n";
        for (int i = 0;i < obj.size;++i)
            output << obj.ptr[i] << "\n";
        return output;
    }
    void operator =(const strings& obj)
    {
        this->size = obj.size;
        for (int i = 0;i < size;++i)
            ptr[i] = obj.ptr[i];
    }
    ~strings()
    {
        delete[]ptr;
    }
};
```

Another class stringsFromNumbers:

```
class stringsFromNumbers:public strings
{
    int numbers;
public:
    stringsFromNumbers(){
        numbers = -1;
    }
    stringsFromNumbers(int size, int numbers):strings(size){
        this->numbers = numbers;
    }
    stringsFromNumbers(const stringsFromNumbers& obj)
    {
        this->numbers = obj.numbers;
        this->size = obj.size;
        for (int i = 0;i < size;++i)
            this->ptr[i] = obj.ptr[i];
    }
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, stringsFromNumbers& obj) {
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Enter " << obj.size << " string one by one:\n";
        for (int i = 0;i < obj.size;++i)
        {
            getline(cin, obj.ptr[i]);
        }
        return input;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const stringsFromNumbers& obj) {
        cout << "Numbers are: " << obj.numbers;
        cout << "\nStrings are:\n";
        for (int i = 0;i < obj.size;++i)
            output << obj.ptr[i] << "\n";
        return output;
    }
    void operator =(const stringsFromNumbers& obj)
    {
        this->numbers = obj.numbers;
        this->size = obj.size;
        for (int i = 0;i < size;++i)
            this->ptr[i] = obj.ptr[i];
    }
    ~stringsFromNumbers()
    {
        delete[] ptr;
    }
};
```

Whenever i try execute this line of code:

```
stringsFromNumbers obj2(N, P);
```

where N and P are valid integers, I get an "Access Reading Violation", do you see something wrong in the code?
I have been stuck on this for almost 2 hours. I have tried debugging and fixing it, i have also tried multiple other methods. The exception takes me to this function:

```
inline void _Container_base12::_Orphan_all() noexcept {
#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
    if (_Myproxy) { // proxy allocated, drain it
        _Lockit _Lock(_LOCK_DEBUG);

        for (auto _Pnext = &_Myproxy->_Myfirstiter; *_Pnext; *_Pnext = (*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter) {
            (*_Pnext)->_Myproxy = nullptr;
        }

        _Myproxy->_Myfirstiter = nullptr;
    }
#endif // _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
}
```

The problem is with this function most probably but how can it be fixed?

```
stringsFromNumbers(int size, int numbers):strings(size){
    this->numbers = numbers;
}
```

Comment: The copy constructor and assignment operator for both classes are broken. That may be contributing to the problem.

Comment: How can I fix it?
What do you mean when you say it's broken?

Comment: Unrelated: the `cin.ignore();` in `istream& operator>>(istream& input, stringsFromNumbers& obj)` is something you will come to regret. Sooner or later you will find yourself using `>>` without having garbage in the stream that needs `ignore`ing and you'll discard data you'd rather not discard. Never discard data before an IO transaction. Instead discard after the IO operation that left garbage in the stream.

Comment: I appreciate your guidance, but that doesn't fix the problem I am facing? Can you help with that?

Comment: BTW, you can eliminate the `this->` syntax by using a coding scheme where class members and method parameters have different names.  Remember, the more typing you do, the greater the probability of injecting typos.

Comment: Recommendation: Back up your code and hack it into a [mre]. Usually you won't have to finish making the MRE because a few divide and conquer passes into the making you'll have reduced the noise around the bug enough to spot and fix the bug. If you get to the end of the MRE process and still haven't found your answer, edit the question and add the MRE.

Comment: Thomas, that works fine with the objects of the class "strings", but they don't when i try to do it with the child class, help me in that.

Comment: If the streaming operations are not needed to reproduce the error, they should be removed from the code in the question. On the flip side, the code should have a `main` function added that triggers the problem, especially if that function needs to be more than `int main() { int N = 1; int P = 1; stringsFromNumbers obj2(N, P); }` to trigger the problem. It's a balancing act. Make the code complete enough to reproduce the problem, but trim off whatever is not needed. Your goal is a [mre] (MRE).

Comment: Side note: If you had used `std::vector<std::string*>` instead, you would have come around all the trouble with copy constructor and assignment. By the way: Have you considered the management of all the strings pointed to? When will these get deleted? There might be quite a few memory leaks. Maybe `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>>` is what you actually need?

Comment: The memory use was not as efficient as it should be, but there were no leaks as far as I can see. The reason of not using the vectors was that I was bound to do that without using STL. 
Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `stringsFromNumbers::~stringsFromNumbers` and `strings::strings` call `delete[]` on `ptr`, so the array is attempted to be freed twice; the second time causes an issue.

Only one of these classes should be responsible for managing the lifecycle of `ptr`. Remove the `delete[]` from `stringsFromNumbers::~stringsFromNumbers`.

If in some other case you've got a valid reason to free the array in the destructor of a subclass, make sure the parent class destructor is able to deal with the new state (e.g. by setting `ptr` to `nullptr` after deleting it), but in general you should avoid the complexity of making both classes sharing responsibility for freeing the memory.

Comment: I'm very thankful to you for helping me out with this, I didn't notice that this could have been a problem. Fixed my problem, thanks.